# continue command in java / selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Here is my code:

```
start:
        for(int i = 0; i<sheet1.getRows()-1; i++, offerRow++){

//just some declarations here, I omitted them

driver.findElement(By.id("tab2")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("new")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("name")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys(offerName);
        driver.findElement(By.id("save")).click();

        System.out.println("Reached 0");

        if(driver.findElement(By.id("infobar")).getText().equals("An offer already exists with that name.")){
            offerRow = 1;
            continue start;

        }

        System.out.println("Reached 1");
        driver.findElement(By.id("productionend")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("productionend")).sendKeys(productionEnd);
        System.out.println("Reached 2");
```

My question is, even though it continues to start when the if statement is true, why doesn't it go to Reached 1? What can I do to make it continue?

Answer (score 0):

[JLS-14.16 The `continue` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.16) says (in part)

> Control passes to the loop-continuation point of an iteration statement.

In your case this `i<sheet1.getRows()-1` and that **is** what `continue` does; returns to the *label*ed loop-continuation (in this case `start`). I think you wanted an `else`, like

```
if (driver.findElement(By.id("infobar")).getText()
        .equals("An offer already exists with that name.")){
    offerRow = 1;
} else {
    continue start;
}
```

But, to `continue` in an inner loop (as opposed to an outer loop in nested loops), you *can* use an unlabeled `continue`. Like,

```
if (driver.findElement(By.id("infobar")).getText()
        .equals("An offer already exists with that name.")){
    offerRow = 1;
} else {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: If I do a break on the if statement, will it start the for loop again?

Comment: No. A `break` would end the `for` loop immediately (and *thus* **not** reach `System.out.println("Reached 1")`).

Comment: Ah. What I really would like to happen is, when the if statement is true, then offerRow would be set to 1, and then start the for loop again. Else, it would continue to reach 1. But it doesn't do it.

Comment: Those statements appear contradictory. I suspect it does do it. And `offerRow` is set to `1` and then it iterates; because the `if` is `true` `offerRow` is set to `1` and then it iterates; but I repeat myself. Sadly computers aren't sentient. Try a debugger if you still don't understand.

Comment: Actually what happens is, if the if statement is true, it does everything before the if statement again, but it doesn't do the statements after the if.

Comment: That is correct. That is what my answer says. Which is what the JLS says. And (almost) what K&R says. You seem to understand the programming statement `continue` (as it relates to Java, not English). What is your question? See also, who's on first...